# Google document viewer with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentviewer, sendfile

I'm trying to embed the Google document viewer (http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) on my Ruby on Rails site and it keeps displaying "Sorry, this type of document is not supported for viewing". My rails code uses a send_file call which looks like this:

```
send_file(File.join(@document.path, @document.filename), {:filename => @document.name, :type => @document.filetype})
```

In the server log, I can see that the file is being sent, but the document viewer is not displaying it. Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: Do you try it with different file formats?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to do it.

someone in my code tried linked the calendar with this in the helper, this is for a calendar, it is not for the document but perhaps it can give us an idea.

```
 def current_user_calendar
    GCal4Ruby::Calendar.to_iframe(current_user.email, :width => "500", :height => "200", :viewMode => "AGENDA").html_safe
  end

  def best_calendar
    if current_user.can_show?(:system_calendar)
      id = Settings.calendar_id
    else
      id = current_user.email
    end
    GCal4Ruby::Calendar.to_iframe(id, :width => "1120", :mode => "week").html_safe
  end
```